# Find files only in subdirectories named OLD with a certain age using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How can I get a nice list of files in a directory tree that contains multiple OLD Files?

I'd like to see only files from directories named `OLD` that have a certain age.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand the question, [Raoul Supercopter's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680881/find-files-only-in-subdirectories-named-old-with-a-certain-age-using-powershell/2680962#2680962) doesn't quite answer it. Instead of finding all files from directories that are named "OLD" the solution above finds all files that contain "OLD" in their name.

Instead, I think you're asking for something that finds all files older than a certain date that are in directories named OLD.

So, to find the directories, we need something like the following:

```
dir -r | ? {$_.name -match "\bold\b" -and $_.PSIsContainer}
```

But you then need something that can recursively go through each directory and find the files (and, potentially, any directories named "OLD" that are contained in other directories named "OLD").

The easiest way to do this is to write a function and then call it recursively, but here's a way to do it on one line that takes a different tactic (note the line continuation character so this would fit:

```
dir -r | ? {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date 5/1/2006)} `
| ? {(% {$_.directoryname} | split-path -leaf) -eq "OLD"}
```

So, what's happening here?

The first section is just a basic recursive directory listing. The next section checks to be sure that you're looking at a file (`!$_.PSIsContainer`) and that it meets your age requirements. The parentheses around the [Get-Date](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx) section let you get the results of running the command. Then we get the directory name of each file and use the split-path cmdlet to get just the name of the closest directory. If that is "OLD" then we have a file that matches your requirements.

Comment: Note that the regex used there requires that `old` appears as an individual word (sort of) in the directory name. This wasn't spceified anywhere by the OP and may likely be wrong. You can also drop the `Get-Date` cmdlet for the date comparison. Something like `$_.LastWriteTime -lt '2006-05-01'` works fine because the right operand gets casted accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first part is to list all the files, the second part filter your files, and finally format your output. You can use [Format-List](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849957.aspx) or table (but I don't have a PowerShell installation nearby to test it :])

```
$yourDate = Get-Date 5/1/2006
ls -recurse . | ? { $_.fullname -match "OLD" -and $_.lastwritetime -lt $yourDate } | % { $_.fullname }
```

[Get-Date](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx) creates a Date-Time object when you give it a specific date as a parameter. Just use it and filter.

Comment: If you think that any answer is great, you can vote it up :) And if some of them answers your question, it's good to accept it.